# Make a dynamic placeholder in Reactjs using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, placeholder

I would like to make a dynamic `placeholder` in my `input` field. 
I have an `array` of filters like this:

```
const filters = [
    {
        id: "rechercher",
        label: "Rechercher",
        icon: <SearchIcon />
    },
    {
        id: "contient",
        label: "Contient",
        icon: <DirectionsBoatIcon />
    },
    {
        id: "neContientPas",
        label: "Ne contient pas",
        icon: <AccountBalanceWalletIcon />
    },
    {
        id: "commencePar",
        label: "Commence par",
        icon: <BookmarksIcon />
    },
    {
        id: "finitPar",
        label: "Finit par",
        icon: <BrandingWatermarkIcon />
    },
    {
        id: "estEgal",
        label: "Est égal à",
        icon: <BusinessCenterIcon />
    },
    {
        id: "estPasEgal",
        label: "N'est pas égal à",
        icon: <CameraIcon />
    }
];
```

The state for the current filter (using hooks):

```
const [currentFilter, setCurrentFilter] = React.useState(<FilterListIcon/>);
```

The `dropdown` menu to select a filter :

```
<div className={classes.boxFilter}>
    <IconButton onClick={handleClickDropdown('filter')}>
        {currentFilter}
    </IconButton>
    <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl.filter}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl.filter)}
        onClose={handleCloseDropdown}
    >
        {filters.map((element, idx) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem
                    key={idx}
                    onClick={() => {
                        updateCurrentFilter(element.id);
                        setCurrentFilter(element.icon);
                        handleCloseDropdown();
                    }}
                    onClose={handleCloseDropdown}
                    value={element.label}
                >
                    {element.icon}
                    <span style={{marginLeft: "0.5rem"}}>{element.label}</span>
                </MenuItem>
            );
        })}
    </Menu>
</div>
```

And the `input` field whith a 'no-dynamic' `placeholder`:

```
<Input
  placeholder="Filtre.."
  inputProps={{
    "aria-label": "description"
  }}
/>
```

I would like to change the placeholder according to the filter that has been chosen.
I wanted to do a function that manages this but I don't know how to do it.
When I was in the `input` field, I'm out of the `.map`, so so I don't know anymore..
Your help is welcome.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/fork/react can you build your projec there, so i can see the useState and everything else

Comment: can u add stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a state of the current selected input:

Declaration:

```
const [selectedInput, setSelectedInput] = useState(null);
```

and u only need to use `setSelectedInput` when item in menu is clicked

and in the input:

```
<Input
  placeholder= {selectedInput}
  inputProps={{
    "aria-label": "description"
  }}
/>
```